# How do I change an object's mass when the player touches it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am making a game where the character switches between human and bird. When he's human he can push a barrel. When he's a bird, I want to increase the barrel's mass so that it is way harder to push. I currently have a BoxCollider2D and RigidBody2D on both player and barrel. No triggers set.

Here's the script I have on the barrel.

```
private GrimScript script;
private Rigidbody2D rb;
public float normalMass = 10f;
public float heavyMass = 100f;

// Use this for initialization
void Awake () 
{
    script = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<GrimScript>();
    rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();     
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()   
{

}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player") && script.amIRaven)
    {
        rb.mass = heavyMass;
    } 
    else
    {
        rb.mass = normalMass;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just decrease the player's mass/force? That seems more accurate, and saves you from having to adjust the mass of everything they may push.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually my reference to the script attached to the player (GrimScript). The collision and the reference to mass work just fine. I made the player gameobject a public variable then accessed the component of that variable.

```
public class BarrelPush : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject thePlayer;
private GrimScript script;
private Rigidbody2D rb;
public float normalMass = 10f;
public float heavyMass = 100f;

// Use this for initialization
void Awake() {
    //script = gameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<GrimScript>();
    script = thePlayer.GetComponent<GrimScript>();
    rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other) {

    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player") && script.amIRaven)
    {
        rb.mass = heavyMass;
    } else
    {
        rb.mass = normalMass;
            }
}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

UE4 developer here. If I were to accomplish this task in UE4. Id have a trigger statement checking if the player was in human or bird form, and then depending on the specific form of the user either set the mass variable to a given amount of simply change the speed of the actor which in turn would move the item slower.

Think in terms of Legend of Zelda and how when Link walks into a box his animations(depending on the game) either slow down or he simply continues to walk headlong into the box with the object slowly moving in the given direction.

There are quite a few variables to be considered such as how you plan on moving the item, whether you are physically picking it up, simply sliding it across the floor, etc.

--EDIT 1--

Upon rereading your post I realize that you appear to be moving a barrel in a very linear direction, in this case a Zelda like approach would be easier. Simply change the speed of walking while either changing the animations or keeping them the same. I feel like messing with physics is beyond your programming experience, if there is an easier approach to something take it.

Comment: I hadn't thought of just changing the player's speed. I will try that if I can. Right now the error I receive is "NullReferenceExeception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" 

I'm wondering if my above code would work, but maybe I have a syntax problem. If I eliminate the part checking for amIRaven and changing mass and just add Destroy(gameObject), it does at least recognize the collision.